# DocumentTermMatrix function not considering all the terms of the corpus in R

Tags: r, text-processing, tm, corpus, term-document-matrix

I am new to `tm` package in R. I am running the following code on corpus but output of `DocumentTermMatrix` is not considering all the terms.

```
corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(text))
corpus = tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
dtm
# DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 20517, terms: 2)
```

It shows only two terms whereas I have more than 15 terms in my data set. Can anyone help here please?

Comment: Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or else this is likely to be downvoted/closed.